# how to read number of channels without ffmpeg or wave?

Tags: python, wav, wave, librosa

This code works:

```
import wave

f1 = wave.open(file1, "r")
num_channels_file1 = int(f1.getnchannels())
```

but it does not work when reading a wav file with a diff bitrate or other property.
I can't figure out the difference btw wav files or other intricacies, I just need a way to check if a wav file has 2 channels.

Comment: I find your question confusing. "**I don't wanna figure out the difference btw wav files**" - who said you would? `wave` is much more than a `.wav` file compare and it's the right tool to tell you how many channels the `wav` file has.

Comment: @PedroLobito thx u , but i just have this "runtime error" that i can't fix when reading wav file

Comment: @PedroLobito, if i remove wav.open() it works ok, but i need to detect if it has 2 channels or 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), "*the Swiss Army knife of sound processing programs*", is also an option:

```
from sox import file_info

ch = file_info.channels("WAV_2MG.wav") # https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_WAV_2MG.wav
print(ch)
# 2
```

---

Python Install

```
pip3 install sox
```

Make sure SOX is installed on the system, if not:

```
apt-get install sox # ubuntu
yum install sox # redhat/fedora/centos
```

Comment: still gives me error "TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not FileStorage"

Comment: i have uploaded the pic of postman screen here https://ufile.io/54b7d6bf

Comment: That's strange, because I've just tested the code on a CentOS7 and it worked. Which OS are using?

Comment: ubuntu. it's strange too, it 's actually working - but not as expected

Comment: basically if i upload 2 files - it shows digit 2 for channels, if i upload 1 conversation file with 2 channels - it just gives me 1 for channels, but it should be 2 channels!

Comment: The problem seems related to the webapp and not the audio application. Try running the script on a command line to be sure where the problem is.

Comment: that first error with "file path storage" is gone - i got the file name thru file1.filename field

Comment: i can actually send filenames of the files i upload thru postman.. but now the problem  is diff... damn

Comment: i did ur advice: python basic_info.py  conversation_2_10_sec.wav 
for file :conversation_2_10_sec.wav
num of channels is: 2

Comment: so it does work and it does show there are actually 2 channels...

Comment: Perfect! Glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

The number of channels is a two-byte integer at position 0x16 in the RIFF header, so you can just read it directly:

```
import struct

with open(file1, 'rb') as f1:
    header_beginning = f1.read(0x18)
    num_channels_file1, = struct.unpack_from('<H', header_beginning, 0x16)
```

If you're interested in supporting big-endian WAV files (which I think are uncommon), you can detect them by reading the first four bytes of the file ("`RIFF`" or "`XFIR`" for little-endian, and "`FFIR`" or "`RIFX`" for big-endian). Then, for big-endian files, switch from `'<H'` to `'>H'` when reading the number of channels.

Comment: how would i know this without u?

Comment: I just googled "wav header" and looked at the table on this page to find the number-of-channels value: http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html

Comment: not it's not working.. when i give file in postman , it gives this error -     TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage

Comment: There's not really context or information for me to help with that. It sounds like an unrelated problem, though.

Comment: i m using postman to build a voice verification project. wav files are customer support calls. conversations. I need a 10sec voice of single customer. so if i M given a conversation - i need to detect it

Comment: You edited the error you said you got -- now it *definitely* sounds like an unrelated problem. I still can't diagnose it without context, and this is getting really off-topic from the original question. Best of luck, though!